# Change page URL without refreshing - is there a cross-browser solution?

Tags: javascript, browser

I've searched on stackoverflow quite a bit for an answer to this question, but can't seem to find a satisfying one. Using the window.history.pushState() and window.history.replaceState() methods seem to be fairly easy, but to my understanding, they can be used in Chrome, Safari, FF4+, and IE10pp4+.
Is there a way to obtain this effect in IE8+ and FF3+ instead of just FF4+, and IE10pp4+ (plus Chrome & Safari) ?

Comment: Read _"Browser compatibility"_ section on MDN page https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history See links for `History.js`. Maybe this can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the [session history management](http://caniuse.com/#feat=history) you can only change the `location.hash` reliably (no 100% guarantee).

Anything else can't be done without the browser loading another page.